# copy only selected information from 2d array to another 2d array

Tags: python, c++, arrays

I made a python code as follows, I want read only offset_time[i]-33:offset_time[i]-1 information from EEG to baseline_before. In python, it works. But, I do not know how to implement this code in c++. Do you know how to imaplement in C++? I want to do baseline_before[:][:] <- EEG[:][offset_time[i]-33:offset_time[i]-1];

Python code

```
offset_time[0] = 100;
offset_time[1] = 200;

for i in range(0, 2):
       baseline_before = EEG[:,offset_time[i]-33:offset_time[i]-1]
```

C++ code

```
int offset_time[2];

offset_time[0] = 100;
offset_time[1] = 200;

for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        baseline_before[i][j] = filtered_EEG_data[i][offset_time[j]-32:offset_time[j]-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `offset_time[0]`

Comment: Your array indexes are wrong in C, they should be `offset_time[0]` and `offset_time[1]`.

Comment: C doesn't have array slicing like Python.

Comment: You're overwriting the same variable `baseline_before` each time through the loops. What's the point of that? When the loop is done it will just contain the data from the last iteration.

Comment: I want to move EEG_data[i][offset_time[j]-32:offset_time[j]-1] to baseline_before array.

Comment: @TakuKobayashi -- In general, do not use Python as a model in writing C++ code.  All that will happen is that you will get confused, or write buggy / inefficient code, or write code that looks weird to a C++ programmer.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have array slicing. You can use `memcpy()` to copy a portion of an array in one step.

```
size_t len = sizeof(filtered_EEG_data[i]) * 32;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        memcpy(baseline_before[i][j], &filtered_EEG_data[i][offset_time[j]-32], len);
    }
}
```